# Dynamically registered BroadcastReceiver instance not firing?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I've been trying to find the problem here, but I can't seem to... my onReceive doesn't seem to get called, here's what I have:

```
public abstract class NoUpdatesTimer extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private Context context;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    public NoUpdatesTimer(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.ALARM_NO_LOC_UPDATES);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        context.registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter(Constants.ALARM_NO_LOC_UPDATES));
    }

    public void scheduleCheck(long delayMillis) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + delayMillis, pendingIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ...
    }
}
```

With some debugging, I verified that scheduleChecking is called but the onReceive method is not called. I also tried to trigger this code from a shell, using:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a rsg.ms.7
```

(where Constants.ALARM_NO_LOC_UPDATES is "rsg.ms.7").

Can you tell me what to change so onReceive gets called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the application context instead of the passed in service context seems to make it work, not sure why:

```
public abstract class NoUpdatesTimer extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private Context context;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    public NoUpdatesTimer(Context context) {
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.ALARM_NO_LOC_UPDATES);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 0, intent, 0);
        this.context.registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter(Constants.ALARM_NO_LOC_UPDATES));
    }

    public void scheduleCheck(long delayMillis) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)this.context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + delayMillis, pendingIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The nature of `PendingIntent` is bound relatively to `ApplicationContext`.
for example its usage with Widgets where the broadcast is outside the application.
so when you're getting broadcast from `PendingIntent` in `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` you have to provide the application context not the lower layers.
I had the same issue once and it took me a whole day to figure this out.